# JS split method causes 'is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant' warning in FF

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have string in js:
     `var str = "A(B|C)D"`
and I want to split it by "(", ")", "|". I try to do it in this way:
     `str.split("\(|\)|\|");`
which doesn't work (result is: Array [ "A(B|C)D" ])
Then I try to do it using regex:
    `str.split(/\(|\)|\|/);`
which actually work as expected (result is: Array [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ]) but after that FF prints following message in logging console: "SyntaxError: 08 is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant"

Comment: Are you sure there are no other code that affects? I can't reproduce it in Firefox, works as expected.

Comment: That error cannot come from the code you posted.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce it](http://jsbin.com/jahukugoku/1/edit?js,console) either. The error must be somewhere else. (BTW, that error can be triggered by e.g. `console.log(08);`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error you are getting is unrelated to the split function specifically.
It might be what you are attempting to split is causing this bug.

From MDN

> Decimal literals can start with a zero (0) followed by another decimal digit,  but If all digits after the leading 0 are smaller than 8, the number is interpreted as an octal number. Because this is not the case with 08 and 09, JavaScript warns about it.

You can see more about it on MDN: [SyntaxError: "x" is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Bad_octal):

Comment: Yes! It is related with string which I want to split, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code, please:

```
str.split(/[\(\)\|]/g);
```

Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Bad_octal). May be you have any extension that produces this error?

Comment: This is cool, but original code is fine, nothing is wrong with it.